# Please make it more easy to use phongap to install an simple plugin

Tags: cordova, desktop, phonegap

Please make it more easy to use phongap to install an simple plugin.

Can it not be done with easy installing a plugin for phongegap not used with cli and will not be.

Can it not be implemented in phongap only select the plugin you want and then install it and it do the rest for you.

Why is it so complicated. This will not atract bigginers to use it.. You can use it as standard plugins but if you whant to install other third part plugins it get complicated .

Please make any changes.  Phonegap desktop installation is very easy but have not any function as install plugins to your projects. It need an expert to make that.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a GUI if you dont like to use the command line. Here is an unofficial GUI: https://github.com/adnanafzal565/Cordova-GUI

[image]

It has all the basic functions (creating projects, adding platforms, adding plugins, adding icons and splash screen, building the app) and works just fine.